# Is there a testm like shortcut in resharper (visual studio) to create a unit test

Tags: resharper

Without Resharper I simply typed testm to create a new test method and it would create a blank method with the correct attribute at the top.  Is there a way to do this in Resharper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, use Resharper's live templates - `Resharper` -> `Template Explorer...` and create a new template like this:
[image]
[image]

See the Resharper [online help](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) for more information.